# Civilization V Gold

Tags: civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I loaded Civilization V onto my window 8 PC last December and everything worked fine.  I purchased Civilization V GOLD   from best buy.  I used the uninstall option from the original disk and loaded GOLD.  None of the new GOLD civilizations were available and my previous save games showed up and were playable.  I used the windows 8 uninstall option, then I reloaded Gold, I got the same results.  How do I get the GOLD options to replace the original Civilization V program?   Thanks

Comment: Civilization 5 requires Steam, so you're loading the Steam client up, right?  Was there a code inside the box (maybe on the manual or printed on the CD case)?  If you put that code into Steam, I bet your problems will be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar issue when I was trying to install Civ5 Gold. The auto-start menu had the "Play Civ V Gold" option enabled even if it wasn't installed yet.

I entered the key in Steam and then used the "Re-install" option in the auto-start menu. After installation and updating completed, it worked just fine.